# Angular refresh goes back to homepage

Tags: angular, angular-routing

allow me to preface this by saying that I have looked at other SO questions dealing with this, and tried defining my paths in different ways to satisfy the first match that angular uses to no avail.

My issue is that when I refresh my page, it goes back to the home screen. In my app-`routing.module.ts` I define my route as so:

```
{
        path: 'coaching',
        children: [
            { path: 'outbound-export', loadChildren: () => import('@newProject/platform-coaching/src/lib/outbound-export/feature/src/lib/outbound-export-feature.module').then(m => m.OutboundExportFeatureModule) },
            { path: 'participant-list', loadChildren: () => import('@newProject/platform-coaching/src/lib/coach-view/feature/src/lib/coach-view-feature.module').then(m => m.CoachViewFeatureModule) }
        ]
    }
```

Then, for example in the participant-list module my router module is defined as so:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: CoachViewListComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ])
```

I have tried making the path be participant-list, I've tried  adding children to it with that path and it is still the same issue. The component it routes to is just a basic container component made up of smaller ones like a grid component for kendo grid.

Comment: Do you have any redirection set up in your app routing? Are you using ng serve or your own development server? How about any permissions/roles-based routing?

Comment: Can you please try to reproduce this in stackblitz?

Comment: so the way our routes work is a bit odd in that the backend supplies the front end the routes it can show, and then the front end of course just makes sure to have them mapped set up in our corresponding routing module